# React TypeScript: useState never updates

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I can't understand why the state.startSlide never gets updated to be 1,2,3 or 4, it's always 0

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import image1 from "../images/carousel/screen-1.png";
import image2 from "../images/carousel/screen-2.png";
import image3 from "../images/carousel/screen-3.png";
import image4 from "../images/carousel/screen-4.png";
import image5 from "../images/carousel/screen-5.png";

const Carousel: React.FC = () => {
  interface StateInterface {
    showImage: any;
    startSlide: number;
  }

  const [state, setState] = useState<StateInterface>({
    showImage: image1,
    startSlide: 0
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const images = [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5];
    if (state.startSlide === 0) {
      setInterval(function() {
        let currentIndex = state.startSlide;
        console.log(state.startSlide) // <== always logs 0 
        console.log(currentIndex) // <== always logs 0 
        if (state.startSlide < 5) currentIndex++;
        else currentIndex = 1;
        console.log(state.startSlide) // <== always logs 0
        console.log(currentIndex) // <== always logs 1
        setState({
          showImage: images[currentIndex],
          startSlide: currentIndex,
        });
        console.log(state.startSlide) // <== always logs 0 
        console.log(currentIndex) // <== always logs 1
      }, 3000);
    }
  }, [state, setState]);

  return (
    <div className="carousel">
      <p>{state.startSlide}</p> // <== Shows 0 then shows 1 but never 2,3,4
      <img src={state.showImage}></img>
    </div>
  );
};

export { Carousel };
```

Comment: Have you tried moving `let currentIndex = state.startSlide;` out of `setInterval` ? Seems like a global variable which needs to be updated from inside `setInterval` each time.

Comment: Also I am not sure if you need to listen `setState` in the `useEffect`..

Comment: You do not need to add setState in your deps array. You should use the setState((oldState) => ({})) syntax, as you are dealing with old state inside the interval.

Comment: Check this out - https://upmostly.com/tutorials/setinterval-in-react-components-using-hooks. That's a good way to use setInterval with hooks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that your trying to mutate the state: `state.startSlide` directly. However never mutate state directly, always call the set function. Mutating state directly can lead to odd bugs, and components that are hard to optimize. This is what you should do:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import image1 from "../images/carousel/screen-1.png";
import image2 from "../images/carousel/screen-2.png";
import image3 from "../images/carousel/screen-3.png";
import image4 from "../images/carousel/screen-4.png";
import image5 from "../images/carousel/screen-5.png";

const Carousel: React.FC = () => {
  const [showImage, setShowImage] = useState('')
  const [startSlide, setStartSlide] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    const images = [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5];
    if (startSlide === 0) {
      setInterval(function () {
        console.log(startSlide)
        if (startSlide < 5) {
          setStartSlide(startSlide => startSlide++)
        }
        else setStartSlide(1)
        setShowImage(images[startSlide])
        console.log(startSlide)
      }, 3000);
    }
  }, [startSlide]);

  return (
    <div className="carousel">
      <p>{startSlide}</p>
      <img src={showImage}></img>
    </div>
  );
};

export { Carousel };
```

Answer (score 0):

You must remove `if (state.startSlide === 0) {}` and increment the `startSlide` whenever it's `< 4`.

**Working demo:**

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const images = ['image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4', 'image5'];

const Carousel: React.FC = () => {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    showImage: 'image1',
    startSlide: 0
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    
    const interval = setInterval(function() {
        setState(({ startSlide: prevStartSlide }) => {
          console.log(prevStartSlide);
          let currentIndex = prevStartSlide;
          if (currentIndex < 4) currentIndex++;
          else currentIndex = 0;
          return { showImage: images[currentIndex],
          startSlide: currentIndex };
        });
   }, 3000);
    
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="carousel">
      <p>{state.startSlide}</p>
      {state.showImage}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Carousel />, document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

But note that is not the best way to do it, more info: [Making setInterval Declarative with React Hooks](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)

Answer (score -1):

I think you could use setInterval in that case, here is a small snippet of code that will help you achieving that.

Please do comment if you need more help.

Hope it solves your issue

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      yourOperations()
    }, 3000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  });
```